# gitolite and file permissions

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitolite

I have set up a gitolite repo on a ubuntu server which is intended to have developers clone/push projects we will be working on.  I'm having a problem with the post-receive hook I have in a repo. I have a post-receive hook in a particular repo checking out to a particular directory on the server, in my case is /home/user/www/projects/. The problem is When an admin pushes a repo (git push origin), the hook checks out the project to the specified directory successfully and changes the permissions on the directory (project) being checked out. However, if a regular user pushes to the repo, then the the hooks checks out the project intact without changing permissions. I already checked umask on the server which is 0002 and it shouldn't be the issue here. I'm uninstalled and reinstalled gitolite but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in "[Git CHMOD post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111804/git-chmod-post-receive-hook)", the permission associated with the Git repo itself could matter here.

In Gitolite, that permission is configure in the [`.gitolite.rc` as <del>`$REPO_UMASK`</del> `$UMASK`](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rc.html) (It is '`$UMASK`' with [GitoliteV3 or'g3'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html) now).
Check if that does influence your checkout issue:

> The default `UMASK` that gitolite uses makes all the repos and their contents have `rwx------` permissions. People who want to run `gitweb` realise that this will not do.
>
> The correct way to deal with this is to give this variable a value like `0027` (note the syntax: the leading `0` is required), and then make the user running the webserver (apache, www-data, whatever) a member of the '`git`' group.
>
> If you've already installed gitolite then existing files will have to be fixed up manually (for a `umask` or `0027`, that would be `chmod -R g+rX`).
> This is because `umask` only affects permissions on newly created files, not existing ones.

Comment: Thank you clarifying this. I changed the variable $REPO_UMASK in the .gitolite.rc to 0027. I noticed that it changed permissions to drwx-rx--- so my guess is the umask value is wrong. I'm going to look into the right permissions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jmdesigner81 sure, if `0027` doesn't work for you, try your original umask value, `0002`, for the `$REPO_MASK` value.

Comment: Thanks! It worked I appreciate it. I'm going to write an article on my blog about setting gitolite as a designer. I'm a designer. thanks again! :)